# Relevant feature requests on Meta.SO

Tags: discussion

Over on MathOverflow's meta, there's a sticky [discussion](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/13/featurerequestsbugreports-you-should-vote-up-on-metasoe/#Item_0) that is basically a list of all the feature requests that are relevant to MathOverflow (either suggested by users, or that users have found and think particularly great).  I'd like to create such a list here as well.

So please list here feature requests that you make on [meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) or that you find there and think are pertinent to this site.  Listing a request here does **not** imply any endorsement on anyone's behalf, indeed it may be that a particular request would be an absolute disaster for us here (for example, site-wide enabling of MathJaX).  The point is purely to bring these to people's attention who might not otherwise spot them.  I hope that people are intelligent enough to make up their own minds on whether they should vote for the feature request or not.

- [Allow low rep users to comment on duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80488/feature-request-low-rep-users-being-allowed-to-comment-on-duplicates).  Following on from [this discussion](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1010/my-first-question-was-marked-a-duplicate-but-i-still-need-help-what-now) where a new user's question was closed as a duplicate but they wanted more information than the parent question supplied.
- [Give us a great say in migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70466/can-so-questions-on-tex-be-migrated-to-tex-sx).  Migration should have a "pull" factor to match the "push" factor.  A high-rep TeX user saying "This should be on TeX-SX" should carry some weight.
- [Can we get a preview of tag descriptions when tagging questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80990/153603) This would provide authors/editors with excerpts from the tag wikis in the question editing window to coach better tagging.
- [Can “Improve” edits not count towards the CW count?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83408/138421) Because often when one sees an edit suggestion, one also sees a few more improvements that could be made, but these shouldn't count towards making the question CW.
- [Can more of the functionality of the old envelope be added to the new drop-down menu?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83286/155585) They keep improving the new drop-down menu, but it's not yet a full replacement of the old envelope.
- [Shouldn't a rep-less newbie at least be able to upvote a good answer to his/her own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1661/155585) (not tagged as "feature-request", however)
- [Would a “this edit is being improved” notification be useful?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90958/138421)

Comment: is this still relevant? it's awfully kitchen-sink-y

Comment: @Jeff: Kitchen sinks are extremely useful things to have.

Comment: makes it rather impossible to "answer", and half the items on this list are completed in some form. Shrug.

Comment: @JeffAtwood The suggestion http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117984/find-posts-on-mso-by-members-of-a-certain-community might serve to reduce the need for lists such as this.

Comment: See also the list of [recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange).