# Is there a way to find posts from this community on MSO?

Tags: support, search

I frequent [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) (MSO). Sometimes I stumble upon posts there by members of this community, i.e. users of this site, and often I find these posts interesting. Is there an effective way to find such posts? That is, is there an effective way to find posts on Meta Stack Overflow posted by user's of this site?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not that I know of.  A while back, I tried to start a list of such but it doesn't seem to have been maintained ( [Relevant feature requests on Meta.SO](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1014/86)).

Comment: If there is no way I'm thinking it might make sense to post a feature request on MSO. Such a feature would make sense for every SX community.

Comment: @N.N. Agreed (though I'm pessimistic about the success of such a feature request).

Comment: I have now made a feature request http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117984/find-posts-on-mso-by-members-of-a-certain-community.